# Split C array into n equal parts

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to split an array into n equal parts by calculating start and end indices. The address of the start and end elements will be passed into a function that will sort these arrays. For example, if arraySize = 1000, and n=2, the indices will be 0, 499, 999. So far I have the below code but for odd n, it is splitting it into more than n arrays. Another way I thought of doing this is by running through the loop n times, but I'm not sure where to start.

```
  int chunkSize = arraySize / numThreads;
  for (int start = 0; start < arraySize; start += chunkSize) {
      int end = start + chunkSize - 1;
      if (end > arraySize - 1) {
          end = arraySize - 1;
      }

      InsertionSort(&array[start], end - start + 1);
  }
```

**EDIT:** Here's something else I came up with. It seems to be working, but I need to do some more thorough testing. I've drawn this out multiple times and traced it by hand. Hopefully, there aren't any edge cases that will fail. I am already restricting n >= arraySize.

```
int chunkSize = arraySize / numThreads;
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    int start = i * chunkSize;
    int end = start + chunkSize - 1;
    if (i == numThreads - 1) {
        end = arraySize - 1;
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: "arraySize = 2, and n=2, the indices will be 0, 499, 999" throw some more light on this pkease

Comment: You can add + 1 to `end` in each line in the loop body, and then subtract 1 from the `end` in the `InsertionSort` call.  `end = start + chunkSize`; `end > arraySize`; `end = arraySize`; `InsertionSort(&array[start], end)`. Thereby you lose a whole bunch of - 1 and + 1 noise.

Comment: Sorry fixed arraySize to be 1000.

Comment: Why you get more chunks is that division rounds down. For instance if we calculate 9 / 4 we get 2, just like 8 / 4. But then if we try to split 9 into chunks of 2, we get 5 chunks: 2 2 2 2 1.

Comment: If you split 9 into chunks of 3, you get 3 3 3.   There is no way to get four chunks, unless you allow one of them to be of size 3: 2 2 2 3.

Comment: @Kats that actually works it looks like. I was trying the round function from math.h earlier, but it wasn't working. Gonna have to do some more testing to make sure it always splits into n arrays.

Comment: @Katz but it won't work for dividing arraySize = 9 by n = 4. It splits into 3 arrays instead of 4.

Comment: You can round integer division up: when M/N rounds down, use (M+N-1)/N.  Anyway, you don't have to round up. Just figure out the remainder, and distribute the remainder into the pieces.

Comment: A fixed chunk size won't work in all cases due to integer roundoff. You can use an integer ratio: `int start = 0; for (int i = 1; i < numThreads; i++) { int end = i * arraySize / numThreads; InsertionSort(&array[start], end);  start = end; }`

Answer (score 9):

Calculate the minimum chunk size with the truncating division. Then calculate the remainder. Distribute this remainder by adding 1 to some chunks:

Pseudo-code:

```
chunk_size = array_size / N
bonus = array_size - chunk_size * N  // i.e. remainder

for (start = 0, end = chunk_size;
     start < array_size;
     start = end, end = start + chunk_size)
{
  if (bonus) {
    end++;
    bonus--;
  }

  /* do something with array slice over [start, end) interval */
}
```

For instance if array_size is 11 and N == 4, 11/N yields 2. The remainder ("bonus") is 3:  `11 - 2*3`.  Thus the first three iterations of the loop will add 1 to the size: 3 3 3. The bonus then hits zero and the last chunk size will just be 2.

What we are doing here is nothing more than distributing an error term in a discrete quantization, in a way that is satisfactory somehow. This is exactly what happens when a line segment is drawn on a raster display with the Bresenham algorithm, or when an image is reduced to a smaller number of colors using Floyd-Steinberg dithering, et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate your chunk size so that it is "rounded up", not down. You could do it using `%` operator and a more complex formula, but just using simple `if` is probably easier to understand:

```
int chunkSize = arraySize / numThreads;
if (chunkSize * numThreads < arraySize) {
    // In case arraySize is not exactly divisible by numThreads,
    // we now end up with one extra smaller chunk at the end.
    // Fix this by increseing chunkSize by one byte,
    // so we'll end up with numThread chunks and smaller last chunk.
    ++chunkSize;
}
```

Comment: Can you look at my edited solution please? Seems to be working.

Comment: @Shan Yeah, that works too. Then you end up with smaller other chunks and larger last chunk, which could be up to twice as large as other chunks. I think it's slightly better do it by having smaller last chunk, because then the work is divided more evenly between threads, for example for array size 8 and 3 threads: chunks 3,3,2 is better than of 2,2,4. However if your array size is bigger, the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: `int chunkSize = round(float(arraySize) / numThreads);`

This seems to fix it also

Comment: @Shan If you use floats, use `ceil` to always round up, instead of `round` which rounds up or down from x.5.

Comment: But if arraySize = 10 and n = 3, I would want to have chunkSize = 3.

Comment: @Shan For that, you could have chunks 4,4,2 or 3,3,4. I don't think it really matters which way you code it. So `round` is actually pretty good, if your loop can handle both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help:

```
int chunkSize = arraySize / numThreads;
  for (int i = 0; i < numThreads-1; i++) {
      start = i* chunkSize;
      end = start + chunkSize - 1;
      InsertionSort(&array[start], end + 1);
  }
  //Last chunk with all the remaining content
  start = end + 1;
  end = arraySize - 1;
  InsertionSort(&array[start], end + 1);
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution in my edit. It seems to be working. Since your's is so similar to mine. I'll accept your answer if I can verify mine to be foolproof.

Comment: @Shan : seems  identical in solution (Y)